# Is there is any way to count number of child objects of account object

Tags: database

I used related list but in related list I have to call the related object which I know but if there will be an custom object then what to do

Comment: You can create / use related list for all the custom or standard objects that have relationship with account (or any other object in general).

Answer (score 0):

What type of relationship is there between the 2 objects? Master-detail or lookup?

If there is a master-detail relationship, then you can simply add a rollup summary field.

If there is lookup relationship, then you will have to use APEX code.

If you want to know if you can use related list on custom objects? Then YES! You can add the related list on the parent object's page on any type of relationship, lookup or master-detail, standard or custom object.